# Diagonal background html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I was wondering if you guys could help me for some code that I was interested in. In different websites like udacity, or a website that my friend is making (he won't show me the code) they have diagonal backgrounds. Or maybe you could call it diagonal shapes, or whatever it is I'm just wondering how to create it. An example would be the home page of udacity. They have the background split and I was wondering how to do it (I'm not worried about the gradient) https://www.udacity.com/

Comment: Some "friend" you've got there. Have you tried using the browser's dev tools to examine the Udacity page? Look for a `transform` specifying a `skew`...

Comment: What research have you done?  I just searched for `diagonal background html` and received several interesting results.  Also, what attempts have you made (if any)? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: [**Here's the CSS**](https://pastebin.com/v0xpNw6K) that you'll find if you use the browser's Dev Tools to examine the page.

Answer (score 3):

This should work,

```css
.wrap {
  postion: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.hero--homepage::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -1000;
    background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02CCBA 0%, #AA7ECD 100%);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -15deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -15deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -15deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0deg, -15deg);
    transform: skew(0deg, -15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class = "hero--homepage"></div>
```